# Segmentation Fault when removing and renaming 2 text files in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, text-files

All Files are located in the same directory.
When I am trying to remove and rename `records.txt` and `temp.txt->records.txt` for 2nd time I am getting a segmentation fault.

I tried using `close()` before and after using `deleteThirdLineWithNumber`. It did not make any difference.

This is the question:

> Spring is also knocking on the door of the "Drink My Friend" vineyard.
> As we all know, grapes love care and work, but most of all they love
> labour, which is usually rewarded with a good harvest. The vineyard
> needs a lot of helpers, so an application is being prepared for those
> who want to apply for a job.
>
> Applications are invited from those who can work during the weeks of
> the spring season. When applying, they should give their name and
> which days of the week they can go to work. The days are given as
> follows: Monday Wednesday Thursday. Candidates will separate the days
> with a space. The farm knows how many workers it needs on which days
> (Mondays, Tuesdays, etc.). If a day is already full, the application
> should not accept applicants for that day.
>
> The data of the applicants will be stored in a file, and in addition
> to the data entry, we should have the possibility to modify, delete
> and create a list of applicants by area or a complete list of
> applicants.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
enum days_of_week {
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAY,
    SUNDAY
};
void deleteThirdLineWithNumber(const char* filename) {
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        return;
    }
    char buffer[100];
    int lineNumber = 1;
    int numberFound = 0;
    
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL) {
        if (lineNumber == 3 && isdigit(buffer[0])) {
            numberFound = 1;
            break;
        }
        lineNumber++;
    }
    
    if (numberFound) {
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        int currentLine = 1;
        FILE* tmp = fopen("temp2.txt", "w");
        while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL) {
            if (currentLine != 3) {
                fprintf(tmp, "%s", buffer);
            }
            currentLine++;
        }
        fclose(fp);
        fclose(tmp);
        remove(filename);
        rename("temp2.txt", filename);
    }
    else {
        printf("No number found on third line\n");
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

void addApplicant(char *name, char *day, int week,char *filename) {
    int weekIndex = 0;
    if(strcmp(day, "MONDAY") == 0){
        weekIndex = week*7 + MONDAY;
    }
    else if(strcmp(day, "TUESDAY") == 0){
        weekIndex = week*7 + TUESDAY;
    }
    else if(strcmp(day, "WEDNESDAY") == 0){
        weekIndex = week*7 +WEDNESDAY;
    }
    else if(strcmp(day, "THURSDAY") == 0){
        weekIndex = week*7 + THURSDAY;
    }
    else if(strcmp(day, "FRIDAY") == 0){
        weekIndex = week*7+FRIDAY;
    }
    else if(strcmp(day, "SATURDAY") == 0){
        weekIndex = week*7+THURSDAY;
    }
    else if(strcmp(day, "SUNDAY") == 0){
        weekIndex = SUNDAY  + 7*week;
    }
    if (weekIndex < 0 || weekIndex >= 84) {
        printf("Sorry, %s, week %d does not exist.\n", day, weekIndex);
        return;
    }
    FILE *fp,*temp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    temp = fopen("temp.txt", "w+");
    if (fp == NULL && temp ==NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        return;
    }
    char buffer[100];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 84*3; i++)
    {
        
         
        if(i % 3 == 0)
        {
            fprintf(temp,"%s",fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp));
            fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);
              
        }
        else if ( i % 3 == 1)
        {
            int numberOfHelpers = atoi(buffer);
            char ch[100];
            if (i == (weekIndex*3 +1))
            {
                if (numberOfHelpers <= 0) {
                    printf("Sorry, the maximum number of helpers has been reached for %s, week %d.\n", day, week);
                
                }
           
                fprintf(temp, "%d\n", numberOfHelpers-1);
            }
            fprintf(temp, "%d\n", numberOfHelpers);
            fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);
        }
        else
        {
            if (i == (weekIndex*3 +2))
            {
                char* names =(buffer);
                int pos = strcspn(names, "\n"); // find position of newline character
                if (pos < strlen(names)) {
                    names[pos] = '\0'; // replace newline character with null character
                }
                strcat(names, name);  
                printf("%s",names);
       
                fprintf(temp,"%s\n",names);
            }
        }
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(temp);
    deleteThirdLineWithNumber("temp.txt"); remove(filename); 
    rename("temp.txt",filename); 
}
void initialisingFile(int maximumnumberOfhelper)
{
    char day[10];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("records.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 84; i++) {
        if (i % 7 == 0) {
            strcpy(day, "MONDAY   ");
        } else if (i % 7 == 1) {
            strcpy(day, "TUESDAY  ");
        } else if (i % 7 == 2) {
            strcpy(day, "WEDNESDAY");
        } else if (i % 7 == 3) {
            strcpy(day, "THURSDAY ");
        } else if (i % 7 == 4) {
            strcpy(day, "FRIDAY   ");
        } else if (i % 7 == 5) {
            strcpy(day, "SATURDAY ");
        } else {
            strcpy(day, "SUNDAY   ");
        }
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", day);
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", maximumnumberOfhelper);
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", "people:");
    }
       
    fclose(fp);
}
int main() {
    initialisingFile(10);
    addApplicant("sarveshwar", "MONDAY", 0,"records.txt");
    addApplicant("sarveshwar", "MONDAY", 0,"records.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably not the cause of the crash but I think you have a type here: `else if(strcmp(day, "SATURDAY") == 0){  weekIndex = week*7+THURSDAY; ...`.

Comment: not there, I corrected it though.

Comment: Did you try to debug the program?

Comment: When you used the debugger to figure this out, which line is the fault happening on?

Comment: The way you're calling `fgets()` in each case of `i % 3` is very confusing? Why don't you just call `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)` at the top of the loop, then process its contents depending on the modulus.

Comment: when i am removing record.txt for 2nd time.

Comment: You mean `remove(filename);`?

Comment: yes, When i use method addApplicant for 2nd time, then when I am removing record.txt remove(Filename), it give segmentation fault

Comment: What's the point of `deleteThirdLineWithNumber()`? The third line contains the people for the first day, so it will never contain a number.

Comment: it does after going through the loop. that I why I created it.

Comment: The problem is that `addApplicant()` doesn't rewrite write the `people:` lines for the days other than the one you're adding the applicant to. So when you call it the second time, all those lines are missing and you process the file wrong.

Comment: how should i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You're only writing the `people:` line for the day that you're adding the applicant. As a result, the file no longer has the expected `84*3` lines. When you get past the end of the file the calls to `fgets()` fail and undefined behavior occurs.

You need an `else` block to write the original `people:` line to the file in that case.

You should also put a delimiter between the people in the `people:` line. I've added a space between them.

```
        else
        {
            if (i == (weekIndex*3 +2))
            {
                char* names =(buffer);
                int pos = strcspn(names, "\n"); // find position of newline character
                if (pos < strlen(names)) {
                    names[pos] = '\0'; // replace newline character with null character
                }
                strcat(names, " "); // put space between people
                strcat(names, name);
                printf("%s",names);
                fprintf(temp,"%s\n",names);
            } else {
                fprintf(temp, "%s", buffer); // write the original people line
            }
        }
```

Comment: What has that got to do with the *question*, which is apparently about a segmentation fault?

Comment: The segmentation fault is because the file doesn't have 3*84 lines after he removes all the `people:` lines, so the calls to `fgets()` are failing and he's writing null pointers.